# how to remove a item in listbox in vb

Tags: vb.net, listbox

the string is looks like 11,33,44
i made a split into three strings into 3 textboxes, and then when i do ListBox1.Items.Remove(ListBox1.SelectedItem) it doesn't work.

it says ss.Split(",") Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

here is my code

```
    Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As System.Object, e As        System.EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim ss As String = ListBox1.SelectedItem

    Dim aryTextFile(2) As String
    aryTextFile = ss.Split(",")


    TextBox1.Text = (aryTextFile(0))
    TextBox2.Text = (aryTextFile(1))
    TextBox3.Text = (aryTextFile(2))

    ss = String.Join(",", aryTextFile)

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    ListBox1.Items.Add(TextBox1.Text + "," + TextBox2.Text + "," + TextBox3.Text)
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    ListBox1.Items.Remove(ListBox1.SelectedItem)


End Sub
```

Comment: but if i delete the whole part in the listbox, the item in list box can be deleted. only if i use split or other method to separated string, it will get the error

Answer (score 1):

When you remove an item from the `ListBox` by pressing the `Button2`, the `SelectedIndexChanged` of the `ListBox1` is being called. There, the selected item will be nothing, so to solve this, add the following lines inside the `SelectedIndexChanged event` before assigning the string variable.

```
    If ListBox1.SelectedItem Is Nothing Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
```

Comment: it doesn't work...but if i delete the whole part in the listbox, the item in list box can be deleted. only if i use split or other method to separated string, it will get the error

Comment: @TonyYang if David's answer solved your problem, please select the Check Mark to mark this as the answer of your question, that way everyone knows it is answered.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
listbox.selecteditem.remove()
```

It will remove the selected item in the `listbox`.