# Remove and Select a file from a List Box

Tags: vb.net, listbox

After many trials and errors, I found hit wall that I need to get through, I need your help, but first let me show you what I have so far...

`LB_FolderPath` is a `ListBox` that contain all my working paths.

`LB_Dwglst` is `ListBox` with all the files in my working folder (`LB_FolderPath`).

When I select a file from the `LB_Dwglst` or I try to remove a path with `Bt_RmvPrj` button, I got the following error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException'
>   occurred in mscorlib.dll Additional information: Access to the path
>   'U:\123409\mech' is denied.

The folder and file is not read-only, it looks like (I think) I need to check for a existing of the file... can you show me how to do that?

Here is my code...

```
Dim folderName As String

Private Sub Bt_RmvPrj_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Bt_RmvPrj.Click
    ' 
    ' removing items.
    For i As Integer = LB_FolderPath.Items.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
        If LB_FolderPath.GetSelected(i) Then
            LB_FolderPath.Items.RemoveAt(i)
        End If
    Next i

End Sub

Private Sub LB_Dwglst_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles LB_Dwglst.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim Path = LB_FolderPath.SelectedItem.ToString
    Dim strFileName As String = LB_Dwglst.SelectedIndex
    Dim selectedItem = LB_Dwglst.SelectedItem
    If (File.Exists(strFileName)) >= 0 Then

      ' ***the error in this line below...***
        Dim fs As FileStream = New FileStream(Path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite)

        ' An unhandled exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
        ' Additional Information: Access to the path 'U:\100000\Telecom' is denied.

more LONG code below to preview the cadd file.


Private Sub LB_FolderPath_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles LB_FolderPath.SelectedIndexChanged
    LB_Dwglst.Items.Clear()
    ' Obtain the file path from the list box selection.
    Dim filePath = LB_FolderPath.SelectedItem.ToString
    Dim fileNames As String() = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(filePath, "*.dwg", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
    For Each fileName As String In fileNames
         LB_Dwglst.Items.Add(Path.GetFileName(fileName))
    Next
End Sub
```

[My project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFIxI.jpg)

Comment: Firstly, what's up with this: `If (File.Exists(strFileName)) >= 0 Then`? Why would you compare a `Boolean` to an `Integer`? The `File.Exists` method returns a `Boolean` that indicates whether the file exists or not. Why implicitly convert that `Boolean` to an `Integer` and compare that to another `Integer`, just to get back the very same `Boolean` value you started with? Do it properly, like this: `If File.Exists(strFileName) Then`.

Comment: As for the issue, it has nothing whatsoever to do with `ListBoxes`. The issue is purely and simply that you are trying to open a file that you don't have permissions to open. What is this U: drive? Is it a network drive or an external drive or what? Can you open that file in Windows Explorer?

Comment: When you convert File.Exists to an Integer it returns -1 if true and 0 if false. So your If File.Exist >=0 is true if File.Exists returns false and false if File.Exists returns true. See the trouble you get into by not treating a Boolean as a Boolean.

Comment: Oops, many thank to @ jmcilhinney and @Mary for your help and clatification.

Comment: Now is working...now the second question: in my first post under the sub: "LB_FolderPath" I got a error in the line  "Dim filePath = LB_FolderPath.SelectedItem.ToString", the error is:  "An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in MyCaddBrowser.exe

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.". That happens when I try to delete (Sub Bt_RmvPrj_Click) a path from the list box and update the text file.

Comment: I found the solution ....   [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17846668/how-to-remove-a-item-in-listbox-in-vb)